# HttpClient throws 403

Tags: java, apache, httpclient

trying to access `http://forum.worldoftanks.eu/index.php?app=members` using apache HttpClient but keep getting 403. Can anyone help out?
Been fiddling with this piece as a starting point:

```
DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpRequestBase method = new HttpGet(theUrl);
String s = httpClient.execute(method, new BasicResponseHandler());    
System.out.println(s);
httpClient.getConnectionManager().shutdown();
```

Comment: When I visit that URL, I get "You do not have permission to view the member listing." which is presumably why you're getting a 403. You'll need to supply credentials...

Comment: 403 means unauthorized access to the server. You need a valid credentials to access the link

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think this is related to HttpClient. I tried this

```
$ wget http://forum.worldoftanks.eu/index.php?app=members
--2011-08-08 23:17:52--  http://forum.worldoftanks.eu/index.php?app=members
Resolving forum.worldoftanks.eu (forum.worldoftanks.eu)... 213.252.177.21, 213.2
52.177.20
Connecting to forum.worldoftanks.eu (forum.worldoftanks.eu)|213.252.177.21|:80..
. connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 403 Forbidden
2011-08-08 23:17:56 ERROR 403: Forbidden.
```

with no luck.

Yet I can hit it in the browser. It might be that there is some server logic returning 403s when an appropriate browser headers aren't sent.  My next step would be to use FireBug and try to replicate the request as your browser makes it.

Also, try catching the exceptino

```
  } catch (HttpResponseException e) {
    System.err.println(e.response.parseAsString());
  }
```

Comment: i did try (without luck) `HttpContext context = new BasicHttpContext();
            context.setAttribute(CoreProtocolPNames.USER_AGENT, "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.1; rv:5.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/5.0");

            DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpRequestBase method = new HttpGet(PLAYER_URL_PREFIX);            
            String s = httpClient.execute(method, new BasicResponseHandler(), context);
            httpClient.getConnectionManager().shutdown();
            System.out.println(s);`

Comment: I don't have a browser w/ firebug handy, but it looks as if the server is returning content with the 403 if that's whats happening, causing the library to throw an exception.  You might try to print the response body if there is one.